# How to properly validate a part of the output of a command in BASH

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a Bash script that validate if Java is installed with the -version output (this is mandatory).
This is my actual code, I get the *else* result, but when I try to echo the variable, it contain the "openjdk" for the *then* to execute. Thanks for the help.

```
#!/bin/bash

sudo apt install default-jre

java_version=$(java -version)

if [[ $java_version == *"openjdk version"* ]]
  then
    echo "Java is successfully installed!"
  else
    echo "Java is not installed, please retry."
  fi
```

Current output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
default-jre is already the newest version (2:1.11-72build2).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 38 not upgraded.
openjdk version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
Java is not installed, please retry.
```

Comment: Why not just `if java -version`?

Comment: Thanks! It works, I don't know why I complicated the code...